# Are there structured properties like in ADTF2?

Tags: c++, adtf, adtf3

In ADTF2 it was possible to create nested properties by concatenating the names with "::".
So property names "Foo::Property1" and "Foo::Property2" would create following structure:

```
Foo
   Property1
   Property2
```

Is something like this also possible in ADTF3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can group properties in ADTF 3.x by seperate them with slashes, for example:

```
adtf::base::property_variable<tBool> m_bPropOne = tFalse;    
adtf::base::property_variable<tBool> m_bPropTwo = tFalse;

cMyADTF3Filter::cMyADTF3Filter()
{
    // ...

    RegisterPropertyVariable("Foo/Property1", m_bPropOne);
    RegisterPropertyVariable("Foo/Property2", m_bPropTwo);

    // ...
}
```